# Как посмотреть отправляемые sql-запросы?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server, sql

Создаю веб-приложение на `ASP.NET MVC 3` и хотел бы как-то просматривать отправляемые sql-запросы. СУБД `Microsoft Sql Server`. С базой данных работаю при помощи `ADO.NET Entity Data Model`.

Answer (score 4):

Посмотреть поможет [SQL Server Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms181091.aspx). Однако он, вроде как, входит в редакция начиная со Standart.

Comment: Нашёл ещё одну интересную штуку, которая показывает sql-запросы и не только: http://miniprofiler.com/

Comment: Да есть такой, я его как-то смотрел, но это лишний код. Если база MS SQLServer и надо только отслеживать активность у конкретной БД я бы все-таки Profiler использовал